# MySQL select two rows from same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables, company and openhours.

**company**
id | name

**openhours**
id | day | company | open | close

openhours has 7 rows per company, with each days open hours ('mon', 'tue', 'wed' etc)

Basically I want to fetch the openhours for both wednesday (wed) and thursday (thu)

```
SELECT * FROM openhours WHERE company=1 AND day='wed'
SELECT * FROM openhours WHERE company=1 AND day='thu'
```

What I'm looking for though is getting both the company and openhours for the company in the same query, but so far I can only get 1 row for openhours

```
SELECT company.*, openhours.* FROM company INNER JOIN openhours ON openhours.company=company.id WHERE openhours.day == 'wed' OR openhours.day == 'thu
```

Any help? Been sitting on this for quite some time now

**EDIT**
This is how the openhours table looks like (company id 1)

id | day | company | open | close

```
1 mon 1 08:00 16:00
2 tue 1 08:00 16:00
3 wed 1 10:00 16:00
4 thu 1 11:00 15:00
5 fri 1 08:00 16:00
6 sat 1 11:00 14:00
7 sun 1 11:00 14:00
```

Comment: You mentioned the query only gives you one record, what are you using to look at the results of your query?

Comment: Please post the data.

Comment: See edit on first post

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  company.*, openhours.*
FROM
  company
  INNER JOIN
    openhours ON openhours.company=company.id
WHERE
  company.id = 1 AND
  openhours.day IN ('wed', 'thu')
;
```

You say you still get 1 row, so I think there is some other issue because it worked fine for me in [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e5da/2/0). How are you calling this query? There may be a problem in your execution or environment. You could also try a `LEFT JOIN`, but this should be `INNER`.

Comment: Only gives me 1 record for openhours which is for wednesday. I'm looking to get both for wednesday and thursday. Thank you for your input though, really appreciate it!

Comment: Same issue, only gives me the record for wednesday (wed)

Comment: Weird.  Can you try changing `company.id` to `openhours.company`?

Comment: Same problem. But isn't it bound to only return 1 record from the openhours table, whichever is first (which is wednesday in this case).

Comment: @Emil please view my [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e5da/2/0), everything should be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT company.*, openhours.* 
FROM company INNER JOIN openhours ON openhours.company=company.id 
WHERE (day='wed' OR day='thu')
```

Comment: Only gives me 1 record for openhours which is for wednesday.

Comment: Can you please post the data of your database query for selecting all opening hours for your company. Are you sure that there are opnening hours for Thursday in your DB?

Comment: Yes I'm sure there are opening hours for thursday. Your query is bound to only return one record from the openhours table, whichever is first (which is wednesday in this case)

Comment: I dont think so as there is no LIMIT at the and of the query.

Comment: I've tried every single modification of this as it is but always return the first match (wednesday). Try for yourself if you like. Been stuck on this for 2 days now

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
SELECT * FROM openhours WHERE company=1 AND (day='wed' OR day='thu');
```

or:

```
SELECT company.*, openhours.* FROM company INNER JOIN openhours ON openhours.company = company.id WHERE openhours.day IN ('wed', 'thu')
```

Your query had a '==' (syntax error).

Comment: Same as the answers above. Feels like I've tried everything.

What I need is to get both the record for wednesday (wed) and thursday (thu)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *
from company c, openhours o
where c.id=o.company and c.id=1 and o.day='wed' or o.day='thu';
```